# List of Months with Years

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

How can I simply get a list of months with years without a field?
Kind of like how we do current_date() but instead a list of month_years to date in SQL/Big Query

Comment: not clear - can you show example of what is the input data (if any) and expected output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unnest a date array:

```
select yyyymm
from unnest(generate_date_array(date '2020-01-01', '2020-12-01', interval 1 month)) yyyymm
```